# Can a function be uniquely determined from its symmetric components about two different points?

Tags: symmetry, symmetric-functions

Can a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be uniquely determined from its symmetric components about two different points? If so how?

Not sure if I'm formulating this correctly, but I've got a problem that looks something like this:

$f(x) = S_a(x)+A_a(x) = S_b(x)+A_b(x)$

where $~~S_a(a+x)=S_a(a-x)$, $~~A_a(a+x) = -A_a(a-x)$,

and   $~~~~~~S_b(b+x)=S_b(b-x)$, $~~A_b(b+x) = -A_b(b-x)$,

$S_a$ and $S_b$ are known, and $a\neq b$.

What is $f(x)$?

**Edit:** $S_a$ and $A_a$ are the symmetric and anti-symmetric components of $f$ around the point $a$ (as defined above).

Comment: Please, explain your notation. We don't know the domain of $f$, what are those $S_a$, $A_a$, et cetera.

Comment: I clarified the domain of $f$. Not sure what more I need to say about $S_a$, $A_a$ - they're supposed to represent the symmetric/antisymmetric components of $f$ about a given point.